# Symfony2: Access the container in the repository

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to show an user oriented choice list in a form and I don't manage to access to the container to get the current User.

I don't see how to get it in the Repository neither than in the Type.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let say you created a `FormType` class. You don't know how to pass the container in this object.

Create now your own type extended from FormType and pass the container through the constructor

```
class MyType extends FormType
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

In your config.yml, define your new type

```
mytype:
  class: ...\MyType
  arguments: ["@service_container"]
  tags:
      - { name: form.type }
```

Now, use MyType instead of FormType in all your controllers

Comment: How would be the classes of the forms that extend from MyType? I cannot make them to work. I got: "Argument 1 passed to Makrosoft\UtilesBundle\Utiles\MyType::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,..."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can request the User object in the controller, and pass it on to the repository in the constructor?

Comment: The repository is constructed in the buildform of the Type, and this function is a static call so I can't get it that way.