# How can i pass a a variable in formbuilder?

Tags: php, symfony

I have find more answer about this, but return error "The option "prova" does not exist "

I make this
in `defaultcontroller.php`

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProvinciaType(), $provincia, array('prova' => 'ciao'));
```

in `ProvinciaType.php`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeIndexBundle:Provincia',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
    },'empty_value' => $options['prova'] 
));

    }
```

but not work why?

Comment: Because `$options` inside the _lambda_ `function(){}` (also known as _closure_) do  not know about it. You can use... `use` with function. though.  See usage [on this page, it's the best found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716776/symfony-2-how-to-pass-data-to-formbuilder/7688619#answer-6870684)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply pass it to the constructor :

```
$this->createForm(new ProvinciaType($options), $provincia)
```

And use it in the form :

```
public function __construct($options) {
    $this->options = $options;
}
```

Then use this in buildForm :

```
$options = $this->options;
....
function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options)
    ...
},'empty_value' => $options['prova'] 
....
```

Comment: the construct i have put in ProvinciaType.php?

Comment: i need to pass at builderform

Comment: $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeIndexBundle:Provincia',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
    },'empty_value' => $options['prova'] <------------

Comment: this say me syntaxs error
return $er->createQueryBuilder('u') use ($options)

Comment: I answered this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643391/symfony2-access-the-container-in-the-repository/7715886#7715886 Maybe it can help you